# SQL Self Join table - All records from 1 table, 1 record from the other

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks like this (in MS Access)

```
rDate      |  rTime  |  Horse  |  Pos  |  Odds
------------------------------------------
01/03/2019 |  13:00  |  HorseA |   3   |  13.2
01/03/2019 |  13:00  |  HorseB |   2   |  3.2
01/03/2019 |  13:00  |  HorseC |   1   |  2.0
01/03/2019 |  13:00  |  HorseD |   4   |  30.0
01/03/2019 |  14:30  |  HorseA |   4   |  6.6
01/03/2019 |  14:30  |  HorseB |   3   |  2.7
01/03/2019 |  14:30  |  HorseC |   2   |  15.0
01/03/2019 |  14:30  |  HorseD |   1   |  8.6
etc...
```

I would like to join the table to itself and display the odds of the winning horse of the race next to each horse in each race, so it would look like this:

```
rDate      |  rTime  |  Horse  |  Pos  |  Odds  |  OddsOfWinner
----------------------------------------------------------------
01/03/2019 |  13:00  |  HorseA |   3   |  13.2  |    2.0
01/03/2019 |  13:00  |  HorseB |   2   |  3.2   |    2.0
01/03/2019 |  13:00  |  HorseC |   1   |  2.0   |    2.0
01/03/2019 |  13:00  |  HorseD |   4   |  30.0  |    2.0
01/03/2019 |  14:30  |  HorseA |   4   |  6.6   |    8.6
01/03/2019 |  14:30  |  HorseB |   3   |  2.7   |    8.6
01/03/2019 |  14:30  |  HorseC |   2   |  15.0  |    8.6
01/03/2019 |  14:30  |  HorseD |   1   |  8.6   |    8.6
etc...
```

So far I have tried the following queries but none are working as expected, I'm sure one of them only needs a little tweak somewhere:

```
SELECT A.*, B.Odds FROM Results A
INNER JOIN (SELECT ODDS FROM Results B WHERE A.rDate = B.rDate AND Pos = 1) 
AS temp
ON A.rDate = B.rDate AND A.rTime = B.rTime
WHERE A.rDate >= #2018/01/01#;

----------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT A.*, B.Odds
FROM Results A, Results B
WHERE A.rDate = B.rDate AND A.rTime = B.rTime
AND A.rDate >= #2018/01/01#;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use an `inner join` in the following way:

```
select 
    r1.*, q.wodds
from 
    results r1 inner join
    (select r2.rdate, r2.rtime, r2.odds as wodds from results r2 where r2.pos = 1) q 
    on r1.rdate = q.rdate and r1.rtime = q.rtime
where 
    r1.rdate >= #2018/01/01#
```

Joins are typically more efficient than correlated subqueries since the subquery must be evaluated for each record in the dataset.

Comment: Nice one, yes thats much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select r.*,
       (select r2.odds
        from results as r2
        where r2.rdate = r.rdate and r2.rtime = r.time and
              r2.pos = 1
       ) as winning_odds
from results as r;
```

For performance, simply add an index `results(rdate, rtime, pos, odds)`.

Comment: Cheers, it works, takes a long time to run but I guess there's no way around that.

Comment: @user2096512 . . . For performance, I recommend an index on `(rdate, rtime, pos, odds)`.

Comment: @user2096512 . . . If performance is an issue, use an index.  That should be the fastest way to get what you want.  Did you try it?  If you tried the index and it didn't work, then removing the "accept" makes sense.  If you didn't try the index, you really should.

Comment: I didn't try it as the join solution suited my needs, I don't think an index would work for me anyway as my database design is abysmal, I may try it in the future if I re-create my DB from scratch.